# How to represent a given sinusoidal equation?

Tags: voltage

I'm having problems figuring something out, and I'm sure someone can guide me in the right direction here.

Write the sinusoidal equation and then represent it for the voltage u(t) if T=2 [ms] and the peak value Um = 331 [V] is reached at t= 0.2 [ms].

I know that the sinusoidal form for the voltage is:

\$u(t)= U_m  \sin(\omega t + \gamma)\$

I also calculated the frequency f = 1/T = 500 [Hz]

\$\omega = 2  \pi  f = 1000\pi\$

So basically my equation becomes this:

\$u(t) = 331  \sin(\frac{2\pi}{10} + \gamma)\$

My questions are the following:

1. Do I need to find out the value of "γ"? And if yes, how exactly am I supposed to do that?
2. How do I represent this equation graphically?

Answer (score 2):

In general, a sinusoid in the time domain (time is the independent variable), is represented as: \$ v(t) = A \sin(\omega t + \phi) \$.

The informations you need are: Amplitude \$ A \$, angular frequency \$ \omega \$ and phase \$ \phi \$.

You correctly calculated \$\omega =  2\pi f = \frac{2\pi}{T} = 1000\pi\$.

The amplitude is given: \$ A = 331 V\$

Now we need to calculate the phase. We know that \$ v(0.0002) = 331 \$.

If we plug the previous value in the formula, we get:

\$ v(t) = 331 \sin(1000\pi t + \phi )\$

We plug also the peak values to get the phase:
\$ 331 = 331 \sin (1000\pi * 0.0002 + \phi)\ \Longrightarrow \sin(0.2\pi + \phi) = 1\$

We know that \$\sin(\alpha) = 1 \$ when \$ \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2} \$, so we impose:
\$  0.2\pi + \phi = \frac{\pi}{2} \$ and solve for phi.

\$ \phi = \frac{3\pi}{10} \$

And we plug this into the equation. As a result, we have:
\$ v(t) = 331 \sin(1000\pi t + \frac{3\pi}{10}) \$.

Now you can plot it:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The equation would look like:
$$u(t) = 331 sin(1000\pi t + \phi)$$
if \$\phi\$ were 0, then u(t) should reach its peak when t = 1/4 th of the time period.,

i.e., at \$T/4 = 0.5 ms\$

But in the question it says the peak reached at 0.2 ms.

So there is a lead of 0.3 ms.

That lead is the phase difference.

Since

2 seconds --> \$2\pi\$, implies :

0.3 seconds --> 0.3\$\pi\$

Therefore u(t) becomes:

$$u(t) = 331 sin(1000\pi t + 0.3\pi)$$

Now you can plot your u(t) on a graph using values of peak, period and phase.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask you one more thing? I'm sure it's logical but right now it just skips my mind. Why is the peak reached when t=1/4 T?

Comment: Draw a sine wave on paper and see the symmetry of sine wave.