# How to find the current's phase given the period?

Tags: ac

I asked a question earlier, and it only made me have more questions. I'll just show you a real example and maybe someone can help me with a quick answer.

I need to write the sinusoidal expression of the current if I = 2 [A], and f = 100 [Hz]. The initial phase of the current should be 1/4*T.

I know that:

T = 1/4 = 1/100

γ = 1/4 * T = 0.25 / 100

i(t) = √2I* sin(ωt+γ).

My question is the following: Is this how you find the period's value?

T ..... 2pi

γ ......xpi , resulting γ = 0.5 pi

Comment: You really should brush up on trigonometry. You can't hope to understand or go further if you don't understand the mathematics behind it. The [previous answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373502/how-to-represent-a-given-sinusoidal-equation) explained very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to write the sinusoidal expression of the current if I = 2 [A], and f = 100 [Hz]. The initial phase of the current should be 1/4*T.

Somehow you have already the solution written above.

A sinusuidal current can be described by

$$ i = î \sin(\omega t + \varphi)\,. $$

In this case

$$ i = \sqrt{2} I_\mathrm{eff} \sin(2 \pi f\,  t + \frac{\pi}{2}) $$

with \$ I_\mathrm{eff} = 2\,\mathrm{A}\$, \$ f = 100\,\mathrm{Hz}\$.